# How can I calculate my odds of x happening?

Tags: javascript, loops, math

What is the percent change of this code reaching the number 200, 500 and 1000?

I created this code for 200 to be 50% but it keeps rolling numbers above 200, someone please help me if you understand :D.

```
var mainMultplier = 100;
var numerator = 99;
var denominator = 100;      

for(;;) {
  var randomInt = random.real(0, 1.0);

  if ( numerator/denominator > randomInt ) {
    numerator = numerator + 1;
    denominator = denominator + 1;
    mainMultplier = mainMultplier + 1;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you created this code 'for 200 to be 50%'?

Comment: I want it to be about 50% to reach the mainMultiplier of 200, about 33% to reach 300, about 20% to reach 500, about 10% to reach 1000 and so on.

Comment: I don't really see the pattern what values follow in the sequence of 200, 300, 500 and 1000, but the percentages you listed already have a total of 113%. Could you please clarify?

Comment: What I think I've created is let's say you want to calculate the chances of it being 110, then (this is what I think) you would have to do this, (99/100)*(100/101)*(101/102)*(103/104)*(105/106)*(106/107)*(‌​107/108)*(108/109)*(‌​109/110)*(110/111)*1‌​00=90.9295890914% Is this math correct? And is this actually what the code is doing. (Note: this is a repost)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Based on the code you have posted, we can see these two base rules:

```
P(100) = 1 - 0.99 = 0.01
P(101) = (1 - P(100)) * (1 - (100 / 101)) = P(101) = (1 - P(100)) * (1 / 101)
```

The second rule can be generalized for any number `X` after 100:

```
P(X) = (1 - P(X - 1)) * (1 / X)
```

Now, I did learn how to do proofs by induction at Uni, which I'm sure would help my explanation here, but I can't remember it anymore :(. So instead, I've written some code to generate a lookup table `p`, from 100 to 1000:

```
var p = [];
p[100] = 0.01;

for (var x = 101; x <= 1000; x++)
    p[x] = (1 - p[x - 1]) * (1 / x);
```

**Edit 2**

And that's as far as my help can go. You may want to post the generalized algorithm on the [Software Engineering page](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yeah so what the meaning of this is, at first to reach 101 will be 99% and then if you would do 0.99*0.9900990099*100=98.0198019801 this means that there is a 98.0198019801% of reaching 102, am I correct?

I'm not the best with maths and I'm just trying to figure this out.

Comment: What I think I've created is let's say you want to calculate the chances of it being 110, then (this is what I think) you would have to do this,
(99/100)*(100/101)*(101/102)*(103/104)*(105/106)*(106/107)*(107/108)*(108/109)*(109/110)*(110/111)*100=90.9295890914%

Is this math correct? And is this actually what the code is doing?

Comment: So, the chances on a high mainMultiplier should actually be increasing instead of decreasing to get the fair amount of odds.